# Best way to assign object to a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, es6-class

I'm trying to structure my Javascript API so I can pass in arguments and call methods.

Consider the following:

```js
class Cake {
    constructor(flavour) {
        this._flavour = flavour;
    }
    slice() {
        console.log(`cake sliced`);
    }
    serve() {
        console.log(`${this._flavour} cake served`);
    }
}

function cake(flavour) {
    return new Cake(flavour);
}

Object.assign(cake, new Cake());

cake('Chocolate').serve();

// => "Chocolate cake is served"
```

Is there an easier way to assign an object and its methods to a function?

**Update:** I can see now that `Object.assign(cake, new Cake())` is not needed, doh. Thanks T.J. Crowder. Still, if you think of any cleaner ways to achieve this let me know.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `Object.assign(cake, new Cake());`? Note that your code would work just fine without it.

Comment: what is the issue with using simple `const cake = new Cake('Chocolate'); cake.serve()`?

Comment: Mainly preference for a cleaner API. Considering there will only likely be one or two arguments which are passed to `cake()` I didn't want to have to initiate it using the new keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line does nothing useful in that code:

```
Object.assign(cake, new Cake());
```

Just remove it:

```js
class Cake {
    constructor(flavour) {
        this._flavour = flavour;
    }
    slice() {
        console.log(`cake sliced`);
    }
    serve() {
        console.log(`${this._flavour} cake served`);
    }
}

function cake(flavour) {
    return new Cake(flavour);
}

cake('Chocolate').serve();

// => "Chocolate cake is served"
```

All that line of code does is create a `Cake` instance with `_flavor = undefined` and then assign all of that instance's own enumerable properties to the `cake` function. So the `cake._flavor` property is created with the value `undefined`. You don't want that or need it for anything.

Comment: Except without it, the methods aren't available to the function. When I call `cake().serve()` it returns `serve isn't a function of cake`.

Comment: @limitlessloop - See the runnable example in the answer. Yes, you can. Your `cake` method returns an instance of `Cake`. That instance has `serve` on it.

Comment: My mistake. At some point it wasn't, I've been looking at it for so long I must have changed something that means it does indeed work without Object.assign(). Thinking...

Comment: @limitlessloop - :-) We've **all** done that kind of thing. Happy coding!

Comment: Much appreciate you peeling my eyes open. I spent a good couple of hours on this because I thought the methods on the class were somehow not accessible to the function, but in fact, it is that simple. I must have just made a typo while I was testing that made me think it was harder than it was.